# How to Trigger a Script when HAProxy detected a Failure

Tags: haproxy

I'm using two HAProxy servers and some nodes behind them. I'd like to let HAProxy trigger a script when it detected any one of the node failures.

I know I can make it drop an email, but it was not what I want. So any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: please, explain what you want to archive with this.

Comment: I want to purge cache on other nodes.

Comment: I think, that you can use in haprox 1.6 external check https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#external-check

Comment: But this is used to check node status rather than executing a command after one of the nodes failed.

Comment: this give you a way to run your own script to check the node status and you can clean the cache of your servers  from your script if the node is down.

Comment: Well, I think it's now working in http mode "[WARNING] 266/115405 (15198) : config : 'external-check command' will be ignored for proxy 'http' (requires 'option external-check')."

Comment: do you set option external-check ?

Comment: Sure, I set in the global section.